# How to list GCE http load balancing?

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

What is the method to list GCE Http Load-Balancing and Network Load-Balancing using php API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function listForwardingRules($project, $region, $optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array('project' => $project, 'region' => $region);
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('list', array($params), "Google_Service_Compute_ForwardingRuleList");
  }
```